# Better Notifications for Suspended Users in Chat

Tags: support, chat

> your account has been automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content

This is a pretty vague message, and to be honest I have absolutely no idea what I was just suspended for.

It would be nice if the offending message was shown to the suspended party, to give them an idea of what specifically they've done that was offensive.  This way, they can actually make an effort to avoid suspension again in the future.

Comment: Are we talking chat suspension or site suspension? Since it's automatic, I'm guessing the latter?

Comment: Well, given that I was able to post this, I assumed it would be obvious that I was referring to a chat suspension.

Comment: You could've just as easily waited until the suspension ended to make this post. Anyways, Meta posts should have more than one tag, and asking that question allowed me to add one with certainty.

Comment: I didn't even get that much. No-one will even tell me what I'm supposed to have been suspended for, just that it's to do with some 'technical system' they won't tell me about.

Answer (score 5):

The "inappropriate content" in that message is a link for moderators, which goes to the message that got flagged. However, it *is* to a deleted message, which is probably why only moderators get to see it.

On the one hand, it is a good idea for the one suspended to be able to see the message. However, at current, we don't really have a means to allow a normal user to see a deleted message (which is part of how chat deletion works and is intended to work). I might consider that allowing visibility into your own deleted content would be a feasible option, but don't know if it's one that'll be taken.

If this did happen, though, then the message link should be enabled for the suspended user.

Comment: afaik, users can already see the history page for their own deleted messages

Comment: I was able to click on the "Inappropriate Content" link in the message Gnome posted about when it was my message. The page said something like 'This is the message as it was before it was deleted' or some such.

Comment: @James Hum. If that's the case, then this is just simply the answer then, now, isn't it? ♪

Comment: I did mention that that was how it worked for me (and Id rather not get suspended again to confirm that :P) but I do not think that information was accepted, hehe.

Comment: I refuse to believe that I could have missed this completely, given the number times I've been suspended.